# Is this correct solution of higher order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the equation $$\require{cancel} (D^4 + 4)y = 0.$$

Solution:
The auxiliary equation is:
$$D^4 + 1 = 0.$$
$$D^4 = -4.$$
$$(D^{\cancel{4}})^{\cancel{\frac{1}{4}}} = (-4)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$D = (-4)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

$$y_c = A e^{\sqrt[4]{-4} x}$$

If it's incorrect, would be great if you can provide solution.

Comment: at your picture is given $$(D^{(4)}+1)y=0$$

Comment: Is it $D^{(2)}$ or $D^{(4)}$?

Comment: Sorry that was mistake, It's D(4) @John

Answer (score 1):

This is *one* solution of the differential equation $$(D^4 + 4) y = 0,$$
at least once we've made a choice of fourth root of $-4$ (that is, a choice of what $(-4)^{1 / 4}$ means), but notice that this is a nonreal, complex solution of the DE; see (3)-(4) below.

Some remarks:

1. Since $D$ already has a specific meaning for us (as a differential operator), we ought to avoid confusion by using a new variable for the (algebraic) auxiliary equation: $$\lambda^4 + 4 = 0.$$
2. There are four solutions (all nonreal complex) to the auxiliary equation. Rearranging, these are precisely the fourth roots of $-4$. We can denote any of them by $(-4)^{1 / 4}$, but ought to specify which if we do. It's better for our purposes to write out the roots explicitly in terms of their real and imaginary parts, namely, as
   $$1 + i, \ldots.$$
3. Proceeding as in the question, this leads to four distinct solutions,
   $$e^{(1 + i) t}, \ldots,$$ to the DE, and via Euler's Formula, we can write these solutions as
   $$e^t (\cos t + i \sin t), \ldots .$$
   Note that all of these solutions are nonreal and complex.
4. Since the differential equation is linear and homogeneous, any linear combination of solutions is a solution, and the linear combinations of the four solutions produced above exhaust all of the solutions. Notice that we can recover real solutions by forming appropriate linear combinations of the complex solutions, and in fact we can produce four independent real solutions, and again, the real solutions of the DE are just the (real) linear combinations of these. For example, one real solution is
   $$\tfrac{1}{2} e^t (\cos t + i \sin t) + \tfrac{1}{2} e^t (\cos t - i \sin t) = e^t \cos t.$$